# new to C; using pow() in a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50, pow, luhn

I'm trying to work through pset1 in Harvard's CS50 class through edX/ iTunesU and I'm attempting to program [Luhn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). The below code is very incomplete but I wanted to know how to use `pow()` within a for loop and utilizing `i` within `pow()`. Presumably, there is another way to program Luhn's algorithm without using `pow()`, but exploring this method has brought this question to my attention. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    long long c = 1234123412341234;
    long long temp_c = c;
    long long temp_c_one = c;
    long long c_one_x = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (temp_c > 0LL) {
        temp_c = temp_c / 10LL;
        count++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        c_one_x = (temp_c_one % (pow(10, (i + 1))) / (pow(10, i));
        count--;
    }
}
```

Comment: `double pow(double)` is useful with floating point numbers.  With integer math problems, consider using integer functions only and avoid various integer <--> FP  issues.

Comment: Note that you can get away with a single by 10 multiplication each iteration.

Comment: Note that Luhn's algorithm proceeds from the right to left and this code effectively considers most significant digits first.  Finding the least significant digits first is actually easier code with `while (c) { dig = c%10; use(dig); c /= 10; }`

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the use of pow by having a counter which you multiply by 10 every loop iteration.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

  long long c = 1234123412341234;
  long long temp_c = c;
  long long temp_c_one = c;
  long long c_one_x = 0;

  long long pwr = 1; // 10^0 = 1
  int count = 0;

  while (temp_c > 0LL) {
    temp_c = temp_c / 10LL;
    count++;
  }

  // TODO: Don't think you should decrement count in this loop
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    c_one_x = (temp_c_one % (pwr * 10)) / pwr;
    count--;
    pwr *= 10;
  }
}
```

**However**, I'm not convinced you have produced a good Luhns algorithm implementation, so my suggestion is:

```
// Better Luhn's algorithm
int luhn( long long cc) {
  unsigned long check = 0;
  unsigned int digit;
  for (int i = 0; cc > 0; i++) {
    digit = cc % 10;
    // double every second digit
    if (i % 2) {
      digit *= 2;
      digit = (digit >= 10) ? (digit + 1) % 10 : digit;
    } 
    check += digit; 
    cc = cc/10; // next CC digit.
  }
  return check;
}

int main (void) {
  long long c = 1234123412341234;

  print "Result is : %d", luhn(c));
}
```